# After the Challenger disaster, the Fixed Service Structures on pads 39A & B had a new structure on the FSS. What is it?

Tags: space-shuttle, launchpad

After the space shuttle Challenger disaster, the Fixed Service Structure was modified with a panel next to the Centaur porch, what was its purpose on the launch tower?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Asked my KSC operations friends, Eric said that is was a "Weather protection wall, it pivots and slid to shield the orbiter from the elements"